# Show image on Spring MVC project in .jsp view (html)

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc, jpeg

I have tried for so long now trying to use a Image on my website that I've created in Spring. 
When I google/search on stackoverflow it, its said that if I wanna use this in the .jsp:

```
<img src="<c:url value='resources/face.jpg'/>"/>
```

I need to implement this in the web.xml file:

```
    <!--<servlet-mapping>-->
    <!--<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>-->
    <!--<url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>-->
<!--</servlet-mapping>-->
```

and

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>restservices</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and in the rest-services-config.xml I have pasted this:

```
        <!-- the mvc resources tag does the magic -->
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
```

And still cant get it to work!
What am I doing wrong?
The console gives me this: `method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/]`

I have the image in the resources folder which is in \project\src\main\resources

the console gives me this when I try to open the picture(which wont show on the website):

```
servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - No matching resource found - returning 404
```

Thanks in forehand!

Comment: What version of Spring WebMVC do you use?

Comment: What is the status of your question @benskiiii? You didn't accepted an answer. Are you still in doubt - do you still have a question? Can you please ask in that case?

Comment: I haven't tried your answer yet, since the project is going to get deployed today or on Monday I haven't have time to work with it. I'll get back to you when I've tested your answer, today or on Monday. Br, benshii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `servlet-name` of your `DispatcherServlet` is `restservices` your `servlet-mapping` should look like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restservices</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `contextConfigLocation` parameter of your `DispatcherServlet` should point to your `rest-services-config.xml` e.g. `/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/rest-services-config.xml`.

As you correctly pointed out your rest-services-config.xml should contain

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

If the image resides in your WAR file/folder under `resources/face.jpg` then the image should be shown when using this

```
<img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/face.jpg"/>
```

tag.

HTH

Comment: I have it like this but still does'nt work. Same error, btw shouldn't it be <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> ? I seriously need to fix this

Comment: `mvc` is the default namespace in my file. Is it possible, that you create a minimum self containing example with the error? You can compare your configuration with the Web MVC Showcase here: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase

Comment: Hmm, not sure. But I've figured out that my project uses jsps or something and that needs a controller for it to work, servlet. So I need to create a controller or something to get it to work?

Comment: If you are creating a new project you could copy the one from the mvc showcase. This is configured correctly. Then you can play around with it to understand what's going on. E.g. setting breakpoints and examining the variables. At the page I linked to are also other resources that explain Spring Web MVC. 
Then you can eighter create your own project again from scratch or you can remove the stuff from the showcase project you don't need. 
I can only continue to help you if you send a self contained zip file with your project that creates the error.

Comment: Okay sure, Where can I send that? Thanks again for your time, really appreciated. I tried examining the showcase, and yes I understand it. I dont really see whats the problem with my project that I cant implement some pictures in it, its only a few steps to accomplish that, but still it gives me the error.

Comment: Glad to hear that you appreciate it. BTW: in Stackoverflow there is a currency for appreciation ... ;-)
Did you try to get to run the showcase locally in your environment? As I stated earlier, if that works you just need to compare the configuration and see what's the difference.
To make it easier for people to find your problem you could post your source code to GitHub. This way people can collaborate on finding the problem. But - obviously - please only do that if it's ok to show that content to the public.

Comment: With the curreny I meant the upvote of answers and comments. Did my answer really solve your problem?

Comment: Partly, I went through the showcase which helped me some, but the real problem was that my controller couldn't handle images

Answer (score 0):

You have not mapped the spring servelt to any url, therefore there are no handler methods for root : /.
You need to add something like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

at the moment, your commented out mapping only references .jpgs.

Comment: getting 404 when I added that in my web.xml... cant even load the website now with a lot of errors

Comment: @benskiiii havce you got two applicatins ? have you tried just uncommentating your existing web.xml as that looks good

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry im not pro on this haha